# UIBarButtonItem style plain change font

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

Changing the

```
NSDictionary * barButtonAppearanceDict = @{UITextAttributeFont : font};
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:barButtonAppearanceDict forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Doesn't affect the UIBarButtonItem when using plain...

**How can i change the font for the plain style UIBarButtonItem**

This still applies to iOS6

Answer (score 1):

This works for me however (with plain BarButtonItem), have just tested it:

```
[self.myBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22.0],NSFontAttributeName,
  nil]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

For using Appearance proxy you can try this:

```
 NSDictionary *attrDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22.0] forKey: UITextAttributeFont];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: attrDict
                                        forState: UIControlStateDisabled];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: attrDict
                                        forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Are you sure, that you implement this in your `AppDelegate`- class? (e.g. in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`-method)

Comment: did used NSFontAttributeName with [UIBarButtonItem appearance], but doesn't seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I set the following in the appdelegate and it worked great:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:21.0]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```